# What is a good Plum tree that is self-fertile, disease-resistant and a heavy cropper?

Tags: fruit-trees, fruits, variety-selection, plums

I planted an [Ouillins Gage](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/47582/i-Prunus-domestica-i-Oullins-Gage-(C-D)/Details) plum tree some years ago and it died after an attack of bacterial canker, although two nearby apple trees, planted at the same time, were unaffected and are still thriving.

I'm planning to plant another plum or greengage tree in the autumn, and am hoping for better luck this time. I would prefer a late-flowering variety that:

- produces fruit that is very good for eating fresh when fully ripe,
- is hardy,
- disease-resistant,
- a reliable and heavy cropper, and
- self-fertile (space is limited).

My soil is light and free-draining. I live in [Manchester, United Kingdom](http://manchester.world-guides.com/manchester_weather.html).

Is there a variety of plum tree that meets these criteria?

Comment: Just curious, is there any specific reasoning for wanting a heavy cropper? Some plum trees I've seen get *big*, and any variety that size I would have thought would yield more than enough fruit for domestic needs - see [this question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/is-there-a-way-to-discourage-plum-trees-from-fruiting-so-heavily?rq=1) for the opposite issue. Unless you're making [jerkum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plum_jerkum), in which case...pass the bottle? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eureka! I have finally tracked down two varieties that satisfy 98% of the above criteria:

- Marjorie's Seedling
- Denniston's Superb

Details [here](http://www.orangepippin.com/plums/m).

Answer (score 5):

No personal experience as I haven't grown plums, but the panel of gardening experts on [Gardeners' Question Time](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/gqt) podcast always mention Victoria Plum as a relatively easy & good variety to grow in the UK, when asked questions about growing plums in the UK.

A few more varieties to take a look at:

- [Czar](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=1533)
- [Early Rivers](https://www.orangepippin.com/plums/rivers-early-prolific)
- [Greengages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greengage)

**Addition:** You may want to listen to, [Gardeners' Question Time, 22 Jul 11: RHS Show Tatton Park, Cheshire](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/gqt) or [direct link to MP3](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/radio4/gqt/gqt_20110722-1600a.mp3), @ 21mins:40secs in. Recommends a couple of types of [Greengages](https://www.chewvalleytrees.co.uk/products/detail/old-greengage/3) to grow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Victoria Plum does have a lot to recommend it but, unfortunately, it is very susceptible to bacterial canker (once bitten, twice shy!) and silver leaf :(

Comment: @Mancuniensis, have added 3 more varieties you might want to take a look at, plus a couple of links to articles you might find helpful.